# Is it possible to have a standalone program that is also a CPython module?

Tags: c, python-module, cpython

I'm not very familiar with CPython's internals from a C perspective (I've delved into them from the Python side loads though!) but I understand the basic principles.

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) says:

> This structure, in turn, must be passed to the interpreter in the module’s initialization function. The initialization function must be named `PyInit_name()`, where *name* is the name of the module, and should be the only non-`static` item defined in the module file:
>
> ```
> PyMODINIT_FUNC
> PyInit_spam(void)
> {
>     return PyModule_Create(&spammodule);
> }
> ```

The thing is, I don't know what this means. Let's say I have a simple Python module / C program combo:

```
#include "Python.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 6;
}

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_spam(void) {
     return PyErr_NoMemory();
}
```

Would this successfully raise a `MemoryError` when imported as a module? Or would it raise an `ImportError` instead?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `PyErr_NoMemory` is shorthand for `PyErr_None(outofmemory_object)`, and returns `NULL`. It's a common idiom. And the reason I want to do this is to make a module that is also a script... in C, by having `main` dynamically link to and embed Python.